# Jersey - Set REST response encoding at runtime

Tags: java, rest, encoding, jersey

I am wondering if it's possible, using Jersey API, to set the response charset at runtime.

If I set it like this:

```
public class MyRESTClass
{
   private static final String encoding  = "UTF-8";

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=" + enconding)
   public String Call(@Context final HttpServletRequest servletReq, @QueryParam("somePar") String somePar)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

...it's OK

But if I try and set it like this:

```
public class MyRESTClass
{
   private static final String encoding  = getEncoding();

   public static final String getEncoding()
   {
      final String encoding = "UTF-8";
      return encoding;
   }

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=" + enconding)
   public String Call(@Context final HttpServletRequest servletReq, @QueryParam("somePar") String somePar)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I get compile error:

> The value for annotation attribute Produces.value must be a constant
>   expression

I need this so I can set my application's REST encoding using a configuration file.

Is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is by extending Jersey's `ResourceConfig` and do a programmatic resource configuration.

```
String encoding = Config.get("encoding"); // get encoding from config file
String mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=" + encoding;
final Resource.Builder getRes = Resource.builder().path("resourcePath");

final ResourceMethod.Builder get = getRes.addMethod("GET");
get.produces(mediaType).handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>() {
    public final String apply(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {
       // implement that Call method here
    }
});
registerResources(getRes.build());
```

Then you should register that custom resource in your `web.xml` by setting an initParameter for your Jersey servlet:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.foo.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
<filter>
```

*See: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html*